# When running CnosDB Community Edition, the following errors occurred. Has anyone else encountered them?

Tags: cnosdb

cd cnosdb

exec sudo ./run_cluster.sh

result:

```
sudo ./run_cluster.sh
*** run meta cluster ......
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/cnosdb/arrow-datafusion.git`
error: failed to get `datafusion` as a dependency of package `models v2.4.0 (/Users/bfr/cnosdb/common/models)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `datafusion`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/cnosdb/arrow-datafusion.git?branch=27.0.0#75f8567e 
Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `datafusion`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/cnosdb/arrow-datafusion.git?branch=27.0.0#75f8567e

Caused by:
  failed to fetch into: /Users/bfr/.cargo/git/db/arrow-datafusion-b823e336e4415a05

Caused by:
  failed to authenticate when downloading repository: ssh://git@github.com/cnosdb/arrow-datafusion.git

  * attempted ssh-agent authentication, but no usernames succeeded: `git`

  if the git CLI succeeds then `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
  no authentication available
*** start CnosDB server 8902......
*** start CnosDB server 8912......

*** CnosDB Data Server Cluster is running ......
```

It seems that there is a lack of permission to download datafusion. But I'm using the community edition, so why would downloading require permissions? I pulled the code using SSH. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a github issue and not a cnosdb issue. According to the official [ssh-related documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)  on github, I think you can solve the problem by re-adding the ssh-key locally. Or more radically, you can use a new key.